# Using in-line styles with JavaFX ScrollPane

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to style a ScrollPane using the inline setStyle() method, but it have no effect on the ScrollPane colors. I've searched SO for examples but none of them were in-line.

```
sp = new ScrollPane();
String css;
css =   ".scroll-pane {-fx-background-color: black;}\n"+
        ".scroll-pane > .corner {\n" +
        "    -fx-background-color: black;\n"+
        "}\n"+
        ".scroll-bar:horizontal.track,\n"+
        ".scroll-bar:vertical.track\n"+
        "{\n"+
        "    -fx-background-color: black;\n"+
        "    -fx-border-color: black;\n"+
        "    -fx-background-radius: 0em;\n"+
        "}";
System.out.println(css);
sp.setStyle(css);
```

There is any error on the inline css String?

Comment: You can't use selectors in inline styles. You just provide rules that are applied directly to the node (`sp` in this case). So there is no way to apply an inline style to child nodes, or apply it to pseudoclasses in the way you are trying here. You need to use an external CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use selectors in inline styles. You just provide rules that are applied directly to the node (`sp` in this case). So there is no way to apply an inline style to child nodes, or apply it to pseudoclasses in the way you are trying here.

You could, in theory, do what you are trying to do here with something like

```
sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");

sp.lookup(".corner").setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
```

For the pseudoclasses `:horizontal` and `:vertical` you would need to register a listener with `sp.getPseudoClassStates()`. In that listener, you would do a lookup for `".track"` and set the style for the track depending on whether or not the set of pseudoclass states contained horizontal and/or vertical.

Obviously this gets prohibitively complex and unmaintainable quickly. You should use an external CSS file for this.